# How to implement start(Stage) method from another class in Java?

Tags: java, class, user-interface, methods, javafx

I've run into a problem where I receive the error: start(Stage) in GUIDirectory cannot be applied.

I basically want to give the user the ability to choose between a Terminal Version of my program, and a GUI version of my program. 1 for Terminal, 2 for GUI. I can easily implement my code when I call the terminal version:

```
if(option == 1){
    myTerminal.printMenu();
}
```

Easy peesy. Once the user presses 1, it grabs the code and runs it no problem.

However, when I have this code:

```
if(option == 2){
    myGui.start();
}
```

It throws a fit, this is my Main constructor:

```
public Main(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = input.nextInt();

    if(option == 1){
        myTerminal.printMenu();
    }
    if (option == 2){
        myGui.start();
    }
}
```

This is the GUIDirectory Class:

```
public class GUIDirectory extends Application {

    public GUIDirectory(){}

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        yada yada yada ...
```

All I want to do is give the user access to launch the GUI version by pressing 2. Is there no way to implement this? Or should I just simply create two separate programs?

**SOLVED** credit to iMan.

```
if(option == 2){
    try{
        myGui.launch(GUIDirectory.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'll have to look further into why this works, but thank you again guys!

Comment: Where do you define `myTerminal`? You could probably define `myGui` the same way beside it.

Comment: I define 'myTerminal' just above my 'Main()' constructor. It goes: 'CommandDirectory myTerminal = new CommandDirectory();' I have done the same thing for 'myGui' like so: 'GUIDirectory myGui = new GUIDirectory();'

Comment: `start` should receive `Stage` parameter.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Look at what @Guy said.

Comment: As a side note, look into [switch case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: @Guy yeah, I tried putting a Stage in there as well but it just says "expression expected." But even if I put a startProgram for example, it gives me the following message: " ',' or ')' expected, cannot resolve symbol startProgram"

Comment: You are missing brackets somewhere or have some other syntax error.

Comment: @Guy, you were right, I needed to create a variable called startProgram of type Stage. So I created one called Stage startProgram underneath my myTerminal, and myGui. However, now when I type myGui.start(startProgram); it gives me a Unhandled Exception: java.lang.Exception. So I threw my code in a try, catch and it runs. But all sorts of bad things happened now that I can't type it all in one block. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitalizerError and Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized. Lots of errors.

Comment: Tried `if(option == 2){
    GUIDirectory.launch(GUIDirectory.class);
}` ?

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489614/javafx2-option-for-starting-application-without-gui/39525027#39525027

Comment: I don't know what `Stage` is, but I guess you need to initialize it `Stage startProgram = new Stage(...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a javafx application, you shouldnt be calling the `start(Stage stage)` method yourself. Instead you should call `launch(String args)` from within your GuiDirectory class.(since that method is caller sensitive). If you dont, bad things will happen, and all kind of exceptions will be thrown since javafx isnt initialized by calling `start()`. So my Application class would look something like:

```
public class GUIDirectory extends Application {

public GUIDirectory(){}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    // build application etc.
}

Public static void launchApplication(String... args)
{
    launch(args);
}
```

Main method:

```
Public static void main(String... args)
{
    // do stuf, and call this if the Gui should be openend.
    GUIDirectory.launchApplication(args);
}
```

**Edit:**
Following iMan's suggestion, there is another way to launch the application without the need to create a separate method for it in your Application class. That is by calling `Application.launch(GUIDirectory.class, args);`, where the args parameter stands for an array of Strings (like in the other method).

Comment: He could directly call `GUIDirectory.launch(GUIDirectory.class, args)`

Comment: Is that a thing as well? Didnt knew that one.

Comment: Thanks you guys! @iMan that was the solution, not sure why that really works, if you have time to explain that to me I would love that.

Comment: @n247s I will mark your answer as the answer because of the edit.

Comment: @Sailanarmo take a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html . Right at the top there is an explanation of the lifrcyrcle of a javafx Application. I think it would be enough to figure out how this works